# How to use import inside of sequelize model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model called events.js where Im trying to import a helper function from a utilities file.
Im not sure what Im doing wrong, perhaps im missing a loader? or this might not be possible?

the code:

```
import { getIdField } from 'utils/utilities';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define(
    'events',
    {
      Id: getIdField(),

      Name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
        allowNull: false,
        comment: 'null',
      },
      HouseId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: false,
        comment: 'null',
        references: {
          model: 'house',
          key: 'Id',
        },
      },
      Date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        comment: 'null',
      },
      Active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        comment: 'null',
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: 'events',
    }
  );
};
```

the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

[image]

my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

the exported function:

```
export const getIdField = (name = 'Id') => ({
// return cool stuff
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: const getIdField = require('utils/utilities').getIdField;

In serverside user require

Comment: If I do that then I get TypeError: getIdField is not a function

Comment: you have to export module , module.exports with object

Comment: defeats the purpose of what Im trying to do. I dont want to use module.exports. Added the imported function into the question.

Comment: Try this
const utility = require('utils/utilities');

utility.getIdField();

Comment: Please present this as an answer. Also if you could explain or give a good article that describes this for me so I can learn.

Comment: Start with learning modules 
https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
const utility = require('utils/utilities'); 
utility.getIdField();
```